# Cannot boot from SD Card on Raspberry Pi 3+ when external hard drive is connected

Tags: hard-drive, boot, raspberry-pi, nas, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 3+ and I boot Raspbian on an SD card sold with the Raspberry Pi 3+, I specify that the SD card was therefore already flash when purchased.

For a few weeks I had planned to make myself a NAS server with my own Python server and React application and stored all the data from my NAS on an external hard drive connected by USB to the Raspberry Pi 3+.

The problem is that if the hard disk is plugged in, the Raspberry Pi 3+ always wants to boot from the hard disk and not the SD card, which creates a big problem because there is no flash on the hard drive and it throws a console error on boot to say it can't find a boot.

Here is the error obtained when switching on with the external hard drive connected:

```
error 110 whilst initializing sd card
```

Priorities are supposed to be SD Card > USB, so I don't understand why it insists so much on connecting to the HDD and not the SD Card, also when I remove the HD from the RPi it boots normally to the SD Card and there is no problem.

I looked everywhere for a solution to this to change the boot order of the RPi but I can only find answers to do the opposite: boot an RPi from a USB flash drive, I also tried to mount the HD but the 'OS returns me that it is already mounted.

So I would like to understand what I have to change, if there is a solution that works with this OS? because I don't want an OS for NAS servers, I really want to do it myself and keep my current environment.

Comment: @Greenonline Thank you for your answer !
I already tried this option, in ```raspi-config``` the boot options are limited to console or GUI display...
I also looked at the advanced options and couldn't find anything to set priorities or find them
I also can't update the tool to manage the configuration because I get an error trying that.

what happens is that once the hard drive is connected, when booting I get this error: ```error 110 whilst initializing sd card```

Comment: Have you tried `echo program_usb_boot_mode=0 | sudo tee -a /boot/config.txt` followed by a reboot?  This should get written to the internal firmware on the reboot.  Also, as you can assume, =1 turns it on.  Also, I am not blindly giving you info from a website.  I use it.

Comment: This is a decent question, but I edited it because the title wasn’t clear and the error should have been placed in context in existing text. Also **bolding** every few words at the beginning is really unnecessary; the details are very clear. No need to bold those items.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to state *exactly* what you have tried, in order to save people from suggesting solutions that you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

My microSD card was simply dead. I changed it after multiple tests which showed that it was an error of the card and not of the hard disk.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).